# Find all injections $f(n + m) + f(n - m) = f(n) - f(m) + f(f(m) + n) $

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all injections  $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that:

$f(n + m) + f(n - m) = f(n) - f(m) + f(f(m) + n) $

I have an idea to substitute $n=m$, since if $f(n)=f(m)$, then $n=m$ (the rule for injective functions).

If I do that, I get
$f(2m)+f(0)=f(f(m)+m)$ and after that I have no idea what to do.

Any help?

Comment: If you mean $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ then you have a problem taking $n=m$ since $f(0)$ is meaningless ($0\notin\mathbb N$).

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: at least the identity satisfies the equality

Comment: @MPW By some conventions, $0 \in \mathbb N$. We need to know what the OP means in this context by $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @wythagoras Even with that convention, what happens when $m>n$?

Comment: @wythagoras : Sometimes, but not usually. But that's why I said "if". I'm really asking for a clarification from OP regarding this.

Comment: @Austin Usually, in such problems, there is an additional condition stated, like $m \leq n$ or $m < n$. Otherwise, it should be assumed. (Unfortunately, the OP doesn't say anything about it).

Comment: @wythagoras : I think we are all in agreement

Comment: In this particular case, I believe that N={0,1,2,3...} and there aren't any of the conditions that u mentioned. Actually, there aren't any conditions, it just says to find all injections for this equation. This is a problem that is given to me from my teacher in discrete math in college and I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: My school uses N={0,1,2,3..}, so I guess there are no problems taking n=m.

Comment: One set of functions is $f(n)=n+a$ for any $a\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting $m=0$ we get:

$f(n)+f(n)=f(n)-f(0)+f(f(0)+n)$, this implies $f(n)=f(f(0)+n)-f(0)$.

This gives us: $f(n+f(0))=f(n)+f(0)$.

Now, recall that we have $f(2m)+f(0)=f(f(m)+m)$, but the left side is equal to $f(2m+f(0))$.

So we have $f(2m+f(0))=f(f(m)+m)$, we conclude $2m+f(0)=f(m)+m$ with injectivity.

and so $f(m)=m+f(0)$.

Comment: Very nice, +1. Relation $f(n+f(0))=f(n) + f(0)$ looks so much like definition of addition within Peano axioms, so the end result is not surprising at all, $f$ is acting similarly to successor function.

Comment: So what exactly are you proving with this?

Comment: Which are those injections that satisfy this?

Comment: @Ana-Marija Did you understand? I'm in FINKI as well, by the way :D

Comment: @Ana-Marija the only injections that satisfy it are $f(n)=n+a$ where $a$ is some non-negative integer.

Comment: @FateMetric I understand now, yeah :DD